# np.where multi-conditional based on another column

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes.

df_1:

| Year | ID | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021 | 2 | 1 |

df_2:

| Year | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |

I'm looking to add the flag from df_1 to df_2 based on id and year. I think I need to use an np.where statement but i'm having a hard time figuring it out. any ideas?

Comment: Find out about `pd.merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to combine df1 and df2 with `outer` ways.

```py
df2["Flag"] = pd.NaT
df2["Flag"].update(df2.merge(df1, on=["Year", "ID"], how="outer")["Flag_y"])
```

```
print(df2)

   Year  ID Flag
0  2020   2  NaT
1  2021   1  1.0
```